# Stop a function, if another is running

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two events on an form input: `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut`. The functions that these events run, effect the came content, and each function takes about 2 seconds to complete all the code. Therefore, how do I fix this scenario: If I was to fire the `onmouseover` event then `onmouseout`, but before the code can complete for the `onmouseout` I fire the `onmouseover` event. When I try this screws up all the code, so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stop one function with another. Javascript events are handled in order one at a time, if your `onmouseout` triggers while `onmouseover` is still busy, it'll be queued and run when `onmouseover` is finished.

Honestly, `onmouseanything` events shouldn't take more than a fraction of a second to complete. You need to restructure your app to do less for these events.

Comment: figured it out, all you need is a flag.